# How to register multiple plugins in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vuex

I already was using the [vue-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) plugin in my project. Now I need [vuex-pathify](https://davestewart.github.io/vuex-pathify/#/) plugin as well.

for the persistentstate I prepare a constant including settings:

```
const persistedStates = [
    createPersistedState({
        key: process.env.PERSISTENT_COOKIE_NAME,
        paths: [
            'auth'
        ],
        storage: {
            getItem: key => JSON.stringify(cookies.get(key)),
            setItem: (key, value) => cookies.set(key, value, { path: '/', expires: '6h', secure: false }),
            removeItem: key => cookies.remove(key)
        },
    }),
    createPersistedState({
        key: process.env.PERSISTENT_COOKIE_NAME,
        paths: [
            'user',
        ],
    })
];
```

and then use it like:

```
const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    ...
    plugin: persistedStates;
    ...
})
```

now I need to add the [pathify](https://davestewart.github.io/vuex-pathify/#/) plugin as well. I tried

```
plugin: [persistedStates, pathify.plugin]
```

but it didn't work and returns an error (`vuex.esm.js?94e4:368 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: plugin is not a function`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vuex doc is pretty straight forward:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html

```
const myPlugin = store => {
  // called when the store is initialized
  store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    // called after every mutation.
    // The mutation comes in the format of `{ type, payload }`.
  })
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [myPlugin]
})
```

Comment: If your variable 'persistedStates' is already an array of plugins, just use { plugins: [...persistedStates, pathify.plugin] }.

Comment: { plugins: [...persistedStates, pathify.plugin] } that was it.